# Automatically login with Active Directory username using PHP

Tags: php, authentication, active-directory

I'm building an internal application with PHP, and can't seem to figure out how to have a user automatically log in with their Active Directory username.  In essence, the user doesn't have to actually log in (as their username password is required to log into their system), so in essence, I'm just pulling their AD username.

From all of the information that I've found online, the most common answer is to use:

```
$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']
```

but this doesn't return a value.  The closest thing I've been able to pull is the workstation username (which is system specific, and has no relation to the user logged in).

Been working way too long on this... any ideas?

EDIT: I'm running on IIS.

Comment: What web server does PHP run on?

Comment: @MetaAdam : I think is `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`? that one is bundle with http basic authentication, [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

Comment: ajreal: That requires the user to input their login details again, which I want to avoid...

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever used NTLM on apache, but NTLM support has to be enabled on the http server (in this case IIS).

This link is for IIS 6.0 not sure what yours is: [link](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/7258232a-5e16-4a83-b76e-11e07c3f2615.mspx?mfr=true).

Once working, when you visit the site in your $_SERVER variable should have either REMOTE_USER OR PHP_AUTH_USER. I've never seen AUTH_USER, if neither of these are visible you can print out your $_SERVER variable and see if there is something else there.

```
print '<pre>';
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Comment: @MetalAdam, if it's already enabled print out $_SERVER and see if there is any item in it with a username should be one of the two I listed.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the Directory Security options,
Click on Properties on your site (or on Default Web Site) go to Directory Security tab select Edit, uncheck Enable anonymous access.
Check Integrated Windows Authentication and Basic authentication (if necessary).
Then you will have the logged user name in $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'].
But! you may need to change permissions on your folders and .php files.

IIS no longer use IUSR_xxx, instead, it comes with the permissions of the logged user. so you may need to give Users/Domain Users or everyone access to your files.
Hope this will help.